# Regular expression that does not contain quote but can contain escaped quote

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to match a string that can contain anything except single quotes, but if the quotes are escaped, it should be matched.

Essentially, i want to match the String `"Tuco"` and `"Tuco\"ABC"` but not `"Tuco""`;

It looks like the following doesnot match the quotes but fails to match the quote.

```
"^((?!\").)*$"
```

What would be the right regex.

Thanks

Essentially i am looking for any valid double quoted string, with possible escape characters if any..

Comment: What about escaped \ like `Tuco\\"` ?

Comment: I don't think you have a good grasp on what a single quote is (i.e. ' vs ")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you are looking for an expression for a double quoted string with possible escapes:

```
"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*"
```